# How to rename a bunch of files to eliminate quote marks

Tags: linux

My iomega NAS, which uses a linux-like OS, has a bunch of backed-up files on it with filenames containing double quotes. Like this:

"Water"-4

"Water"-5

etc. (don't ask how they got there; they were originally created on a Mac)

This is causing problems when I try to copy the files to a backup drive: the quote marks are apparently causing the copy to fail. (The built-in copy facility uses rsync, but a rather old version.)

Is there a terminal command to batch-rename these files, just deleting the quote marks? Failing that, is there a command to rename them one at a time? The quote marks seem to really be messing things up (I know: the user has been warned!)

Comment: I should note that a few of the filenames also contain spaces (outside the portion within the quote marks). For example: "Water"-10 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple single line bash code:

```
for f in *; do mv -i "$f" "${f//[\"[:space:]]}"; done
```

`$f` is your current file name and `${f//[\"[:space:]]}` is your bash substring replacer which stands for: 
 in this `f` (file name), `//` (replace) these `[\"[:space:]]` (characters) with nothing[1].

NOTE 1: string replacement statement: `${string//substring/replacement}`; because you don't need to replace your substring to nothing, leave `/replacement` to blank.

NOTE 2: `[\"[:space:]]` is `expr` regular expression.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Is there a way to do this recursively in subdirectories? And rather than removing a character (or string), can it be _replaced_ by a character (or string)?

Comment: you can use `find` command in for loop: `for f in $(find . -iname "*");`. to replace, I mentioned bash string replacement syntax in NOTE 1, for example: `"${f//[\"[:space:]/_}"` will replace all double quotes and spaces to underline.

Comment: Question: aren't you missing a right square bracket after [:space:] in your first line of code? It seemed to work the way you have it, but it appears to be inconsistent with your explanation.

Comment: yes, I edit them ;): you can use find command in for loop: `for f in $(find . -iname "*");`. to replace, I mentioned bash string replacement syntax in NOTE 1, for example: `"${f//[\"[:space:]]/_}"` will replace all double quotes and spaces to underline.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on the files and use `mv`:

```
for i in *
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/"//'`"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
$ rename -n 's/"//' *Water*
```

and remove the `-n` switch when your tests will be OK.

Take care, you need the perl's version of [rename](/questions/tagged/rename), there's sometimes another versions installed depends of your distro. If you don't have it, try to search `prename` or visit https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL